# Call inner asynctask from parent fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, interface, android-asynctask

I want to call an inner asynctask which is located in a fragment. I want to call that asynctask from the parent fragment that is hosting this fragment with asynctask. This parent fragment includes a viewpager with multiple fragments. 
I know I have to use an interface and tried something but it doesn't work.

**INTERFACE**

```
public interface OnFragmentButtonListener {
    void onMyButtonClicked();
}
```

**FRAGMENT**

```
public class FragmentQueue extends SherlockFragment implements OnFragmentButtonListener
{
...
    @Override
    public void onMyButtonClicked() {
        new LoadQueueTask().execute();
    }
}
```

**PARENT FRAGMENT**

```
public class ParentFragment extends SherlockFragment{
...
    refresh.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((OnFragmentButtonListener)getActivity()).onMyButtonClicked();
        }
    });
}
```

**ERROR**

```
11-12 23:15:14.115: E/AndroidRuntime(31864): java.lang.ClassCastException: nl.name.projectname.ProjectName cannot be cast to nl.name.projectName.OnFragmentButtonListener
11-12 23:15:14.115: E/AndroidRuntime(31864):    at nl.name.projectname.fragments.ParentFragment$LoadInfoTask$1.onClick(ParentFragment.java:323)
11-12 23:15:14.115: E/AndroidRuntime(31864):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4445)
11-12 23:15:14.115: E/AndroidRuntime(31864):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18446)
11-12 23:15:14.115: E/AndroidRuntime(31864):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-12 23:15:14.115: E/AndroidRuntime(31864):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-12 23:15:14.115: E/AndroidRuntime(31864):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-12 23:15:14.115: E/AndroidRuntime(31864):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
11-12 23:15:14.115: E/AndroidRuntime(31864):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-12 23:15:14.115: E/AndroidRuntime(31864):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-12 23:15:14.115: E/AndroidRuntime(31864):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
11-12 23:15:14.115: E/AndroidRuntime(31864):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
11-12 23:15:14.115: E/AndroidRuntime(31864):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You're calling onMyButtonClicked() on the Activity rather than the child fragment.

Comment: Can you give me an example on how to fix this, because im completly stuck.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to call onMyButtonClicked on the parent Activity, rather than the child FragmentQueue instance. In your onClick method, you need to get a reference to the FragmentQueue instance, and then call onMyButtonClicked. Something like this:

```
refresh.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FragmentQueue");
        if (fragment instanceof FragmentQueue) {
            ((FragmentQueue)fragment).onMyButtonClicked();
        }
    }
});
```

Note that for this to work, you would have to set the fragment tag to "FragmentQueue" when you construct the fragment (either in XML or code).